# mssql2019 service will fail too start after I deleted log folder

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

My mssql2019 instance on Ubuntu is not working properly. Actually I removed log folder under this directory `/var/opt/mssql` and now after I'm starting mssql using `systemctl` it will start but after one request to database it's service will stop working. How to figure out what's the problem? Is there a crashdump or something similar?

[image]

Comment: It will also fail if you delete the data folder, or the binaries folder. You nuked all databases. Don't delete things if you don't understand what they do

Comment: `is there a crashdump or something similar?` that's what you deleted. The transaction logs contain the transaction records used to recover from unexpected shutdowns. **All** database products, even SQLite, have such logs, even if they call them by other names (redo log, WAL log, whatever). They need to be backed up the same way the data files do. The easiest option right now is to restore from a full database backup.

Comment: *"actually I removed log folder under this directory /var/opt/mssql "* Why did did you even think that was a good idea...

Comment: You can try recovering the databases, [but that's a manual, complex process](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-rebuild-a-database-with-a-corrupted-or-deleted-sql-server-transaction-log-file/)

Comment: Did you delete the logs because they grew too big? That's probably because you haven't taken a transaction log backup in a long time. The solution is to take a transaction log backup, not delete the transaction logs

Comment: yes that's getting bigger and bigger by the time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "You nuked all databases" LOL

Comment: @Omid it's not funny or an exaggeration. Remember when GitLab lost 1 week of customer source data? They had the excuse of an ongoing crisis.

Comment: @happykratos if they grew bigger you should have taken the appropriate action, posted an SO question, or better yet, search SO for the answer.  Similar questions have been asked a lot of times in the past

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So what's the solution for huge sized db logs?

Comment: @Omid back them up. They're big because they haven't been backed up yet. That's very well documented, part of all courses and tutorials, especially when recovery is discussed. You can switch the recovery mode to `SIMPLE` but in that case if anything goes wrong the server won't be able to recover the databases by replaying transactions, requiring a database restore

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks a lot man

Comment: And the `logs` folder contains the ERRORLOG, system traces and crash dumps.  Database log files are in the data folder by default.